# How can I refer images from local folder and map it and show the images according to the data in my array in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make cards and it would show info from the array I created along with the photos.So i tried to import my photos using the require and then use that value in my array.I want to map through the array as well as show pictures according to like the index or id. When I was using an api to fetch images I did not have any problem but I am having problems when I am trying to import the images from the local folder. Please suggest me some solution if my way is not correct or if I have some mistakes in the code

```
//array 

var flower = require("./a.jpg");
var cat =  require("./b.jpg");
export const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Leanne Graham',
    email: 'Bret',
    src: flower
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Ervin Howell',
    email: 'Antonette',
    src: cat

  }
];
// the card component
import React from 'react';
const Card = ({ name, email, id,src }) => {
  return (
    <div className='tc grow bg-light-green br3'>
      <img alt='robots' src={src} />
      <div>
        <h2>{name}</h2>
        <p>{email}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Card;
//the main component for listing them
import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card'
const Showdata = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        data.map((user, i) => {
          return (
            <Card
              key={i}
              src=  {data[i].src}
              id={data[i].id}
              name={data[i].name}
              email={data[i].email}
              />
          );
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}
export default Showdata;
```

Comment: Is the issue that the image doesn't show?

Comment: that's one of the issues but also my cards are not loading along with the images so basically something is wrong with my code.I feel like it might be in my array or im not properly being able to map them

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would advise that you move all your images to the public folder since they are statics. You can create and `assets` folder in the root public folder so you can have a path like `/assets/images/image.png`. And in you `map`, the `user` already represents each `object` so you don't need to do `data[i]`.

```js
//array 

//var flower = require("./a.jpg");
//var cat =  require("./b.jpg");

export const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Leanne Graham',
    email: 'Bret',
    src: '/assets/images/a.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Ervin Howell',
    email: 'Antonette',
    src:'/assets/images/b.jpg'

  }
];
// the card component
import React from 'react';
const Card = ({ name, email, id,src }) => {
  return (
    <div className='tc grow bg-light-green br3'>
      <img alt='robots' src={src} />
      <div>
        <h2>{name}</h2>
        <p>{email}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Card;
//the main component for listing them
import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card'
const Showdata = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        data.map((user, i) => {
          return (
            <Card
              key={i}
              src={user.src}
              id={user.id}
              name={user.name}
              email={user.email}
              />
          );
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}
export default Showdata;
```

Comment: thanks man it worked i didnt have to change the path though but i had problems in the map function and just used user instead of data[i].id

Comment: Yea. the path would work the way it is, it is just advised you do it that way. Can you check as the accepted answer. Thanks